# Liquibase Stored Procedure throws SQL syntax error

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax-error, liquibase

I'm developping an app running stored procedures on an Oracle database. It works fine but now i'm trying to run procedures with Liquibase to have an independant environment and I can't get it to work. Even the simpliest 'Hello world' example gives me a SQL syntax error.

I'm just giving you the xml and error for now because i don't think it comes from the Spring part since it's working with the DB. The 'hello world' procedure itself works fine if I run it on SqlDeveloper.

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't have a clue what's wrong with this. Thank you !

The procedure :

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">

    <changeSet id="PROC_PKG_ACCEPTOR_P_ACCEPTORMISCINIT-create"
               author="sth" runOnChange="true">
        <createProcedure dbms="h2, oracle"
                         encoding="UTF-8"
                         procedureName="TESTHELLO"
                         relativeToChangelogFile="true">
            CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTHELLO
            IS
            BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
            END;
        </createProcedure>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The error :

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Erreur de syntaxe dans linstruction SQL {0}; attendu {1}
Syntax error in SQL statement {0}; expected {1}; SQL statement:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTHELLO
            IS
            BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
            END [42001-197] [Failed SQL: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTHELLO
            IS
            BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
            END]
```

Comment: Why is SO deleting the part where I say Hello. Hello !

Comment: That `create procedure` will not work with H2, so most probably that's where the error comes from.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know the correct syntax ? I'm not really familiar to SQL...

Comment: Notice that the correct syntax for stored procedures is `CREATE OR ALTER` rather than `CREATE OR REPLACE` that is used for tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

So you can't do what I was trying at all with H2, seems the solution is to create an Alias for a Java function.

Thanks you guys